# Is it appropriate to run PCA on a subset of variables?

Tags: regression, pca

I was thinking about using PCA to deal with issues of multicollinearity on my dataset. I was wondering how appropriate it is to run PCA on only subsets of variables that seem to have issues of collinearity.

For example, if I had a dataset with 10 independent variables, and 5 of them seemed to suffer from multicollinearity, would it be appropriate to just run PCA on those five variables and leave the other 5 in their original state?

Comment: It depends: what analysis do you wish ultimately to carry out?

Comment: Aim is to do binary classification so something like logistic regression.

Comment: Why would collinearity matter for that?  (In many cases, it wouldn't matter at all, but maybe yours is special.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but multicollinearity won't have any major impact on my model's ability to fit the data or make predictions. The issue I think I might have with multicollinearity is automatic variable selection. I may want to use something like the LASSO for variable selection, in which case multicollinearity may be a problem.

Comment: Collinearity does not affect your ability to make predictions. It can affect variable selection, but, then so would PCA.